# conditional probability question(BAYES theorem)

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

An insurance company believes that 30% of drivers are careless, and that the probability of a driver having an
accident in any one year is 0.4 for a careless driver and 0.2 for a careful driver. Find the probability that a driver will
have an accident next year given that she has had an accident this year.

my lecturer used

P(C/A) * P(A|C) + P(C'/A) * P(A|C')

i dont understand why, please help me

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: *Help me* is not a question. What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30% drivers are careless , P(C) = 0.3

P(A|C) = probability that a person has accident given that they are careless = 0.4

Similarly P(A|C') = 0.2 [Where C' is non careless drivers]

Now she could be a careless ***OR*** careful driver who had accident last year.

Probability that she is careless given that she had and accident= P(C|A)

Probability that she will meet accident next year if she is careless = P(A|C)

Therefore,
Probability that she will meet accident next year if she is careless ***AND*** had an accident last year = P(A|C)P(C|A)

If you understood this part then you will be able to solve the case where she is **NOT** careless

Remember we used ***OR*** in the beginning so you should add those cases to get,

P = P(C|A)P(A|C) + P(C'|A)P(A|C')

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, i was able to understand it. I had to draw a tree diagram, then i was able to understand why P = P(C|A)P(A|C) + P(C'|A)P(A|C') was used.